# How do I identify which barcode scanner scanned a label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode

I have a Rails app that tracks our products through the manufacturing process. I would like to have a barcode scanner at each work station and have the employee scan the barcode for an item when he has finished the work for that item.

The `StatusUpdate#new` view has a text field that accepts a barcode scanned item number and creates a record for that item number and the current time. I would like to be able to also identify which scanner scanned the barcode.

Is it possible to identify which of 10 barcode scanners has been used?

I know some scanners are capable of entering a prefix before the scanned barcode, so I could parse that prefix to identify the scanner used. I am hoping there may be another solution.

Comment: The scanners are simply an interface in and wouldn't be enumerated. 

You could have it that they log in based on which scanner is at that terminal and you could leverage that.

Comment: What type of barcode scanners are you using (manufacturer& P/N) and how are you connecting them to your system?

Comment: Can you have the worker scan a barcode anchored to their station, then the item can be scanned? This would require two text fields per form. You could make the station and item barcodes "incompatible" so the form couldn't mix them up.

Comment: The scanners will all be connected to a remote workstation, there won't be a monitor near the scanners. This is in a manufacturing environment and I want to keep it as simple as possible for the workers to use. I don't want them to have to scan and identifier every time because it complicates the process for them and the software.

Answer (score 1):

I have connected multiple scanners to a workstation in a manufacturing environment and have been able to configure the software to tell which scanner is reading what code. This was done by setting the scanners to act as a serial device (virtual COM port over USB) and getting the software to listen on each serial port.

Without knowing more about what scanning device and the connectivity I can't really comment on if this would work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If barcode scanners are using different workstations then you may try to identify them by the IP address the request comes from.
If you can add symbol to the barcode value then you may just extract that symbol as the identifier. If you are using [Code 128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) barcode then you may also additionally verify if the reminding data correct or not using the [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Check_digit_calculation).

Comment: The scanners will all be hooked to the same workstation, so I can't use the IP of the request. Our current barcode scanners don't have the ability to add prefix characters.

Comment: If no other input devices then what if you put another special barcode required to be scanned before/after main barcode? And use that "control" barcode with special value like "00000001", "000002" to identify the station?   Your app then should look for the previous/second barcode in a batch as the source station identifier